# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to R $ defined by $f(x)=x+\frac{16 \pi^2}{x}-\cos x$ and the minimum value of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus

Let $f:(0,\infty)\to R $ defined by $$f(x)=x+\frac{16 \pi^2}{x}-\cos x.$$ and the minimum value of $f(x)$ can be expressed as $a\pi-b$. Find $a+b$.

Comment: I take $a$ is a integer? what have you tried?

Comment: If the minimum is at $x_0=a\pi+b$ then it is also at $a'\pi-b'=(a-h)\pi-(b+h\pi)$, but $a'+b'=a+b+(\pi-1)h\ne a+b$ for $h\ne 0$. Without restricting $a,b$ to $\mathbb Z$ or $\mathbb Q$, say, the problem statement makes no sense.

Comment: I differentiated $f(x)$ and put $f'(x)=1-frac{16\pi^2}{x^2}+sinx=0$ and then  i could not find critical point.I was trying to find minimum value of f(x) by first derivative test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**: $x+\dfrac{16\pi^2}{x} \geq 8\pi$, $-\cos x \geq -1$

Comment: Thanks, i understood how you solved it.